# Time taken by `less` command to show output

Tags: linux, bash, time

I have a script that produces a lot of output. The script pauses for a few seconds at point `T`.

Now I am using the `less` command to analyze the output of the script.
So I execute `./script | less`. I leave it running for sufficient time so that the script would have finished executing.

Now I go through the output of the less command by pressing Pg Down key. Surprisingly while scrolling at the point `T` of the output I notice the pause of few seconds again.

The script does not expect any input and would have definitely completed by the time I start analyzing the output of less.

Can someone explain how the pause of few seconds is noticable in the output of less when the script would have finished executing?

Comment: Perhaps that particular page of the output has a very large amount of text, for example if there is an extremely long horizontal line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your script is communicating with `less` via a **pipe**.  Pipe is an in-memory stream of bytes that connects two endpoints: your script and the `less` program, the former writing output to it, the latter reading from it.

As pipes are in-memory, it would be not pleasant if they grew arbitrarily large.  So, by default, there's a limit of data that can be inside the pipe (written, but not yet read) at any given moment.  By default it's 64k on Linux.  If the pipe is full, and your script tries to write to it, the write blocks.  So *your script isn't actually working, it stopped at some point when doing a `write()` call*.

How to overcome this?  Adjusting defaults is a bad option; what is used instead is allocating a buffer in the reader, so that it reads into the buffer, freeing the pipe and thus letting the writing program work, but shows to you (or handles) only a part of the output.  `less` has such a buffer, and, by default, expands it automatically, However, it doesn't fill it in the background, it only fills it as you read the input.

So what would solve your problem is reading the file until the end (like you would normally press <kbd>G</kbd>), and then going back to the beginning (like you would normally press <kbd>g</kbd>).  The thing is that you may specify these commands via command line like this:

```
./script | less +Gg
```

You should note, however, that you will have to wait until the whole script's output loads into memory, so you won't be able to view it at once.  `less` is insufficiently sophisticated for that.  But if that's what you really need (browsing the beginning of the output while the `./script` is still computing its end), you might want to use a temporary file:

```
 ./script >x & less x ; rm x
```

Comment: what if the script writes to the standard output and segfaults somewhere in between. The segfault can prevent the buffered output from being written to the file x. This is because output to a file is block buffered by default and not line buffered. Can I externally enforce line buffering on the script? Is there an off the shelf pseudo tty utility I could use?

Answer (score 2):

The pipe is full at the OS level, so `script` blocks until `less` consumes some of it.

Comment: This seems quite easily testable, if you just get your script to emit things to a log file as it outputs text.

Answer (score 2):

Flow control. Your script is effectively being paused while less is paging.

If you want to make sure that your command completes before you use less interactively, invoke less as `less +G` and it will read to the end of the input, you can then return to the start by typing `1G` into less.

Answer (score 2):

For some background information there's also a nice article by Alexander Sandler called "How less processes its input"!

http://www.alexonlinux.com/how-less-processes-its-input

Answer (score 0):

```
Can I externally enforce line buffering on the script? 
Is there an off the shelf pseudo tty utility I could use?
```

You may try to use the `script` command to turn on line-buffering output mode.

```
script -q /dev/null ./script | less      # FreeBSD, Mac OS X
script -c "./script" /dev/null | less    # Linux
```

For more alternatives in this respect please see: [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe/).